# Error while installing Crystal Server on Solaris 11

Tags: linux, crystal-reports, server, solaris, crystal-reports-server

i'm trying to run the setup.sh from the command line in solaris and i get the following error`/export/home/CRS_2013_SP1_SERVER_COMP_LNX__64B__/DATA_UNITS/CRServer_lnx/setupexe -launchedFromSH
setupexe: Cannot find /lib/ld-linux.so.2
setup.sh: line 159: 3695: Killed
Finished, return code is 265`

i have been struggling finding that package but all i seem to find is yum install and ubuntu but for solaris no help, i also tryed libtool but didn't resolve the dependency problem.

Comment: Please be precise in what product you are trying to install. Do you mean [SAP Crystal Server](http://www.crystalreports.com/crystal-reports-server/) ? I've found [this note](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/507d3365-009b-3010-04b0-e5abc8f00c91?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&58475979744666) for you. It basically says that the product is indeed supported on Solaris 11 but only on SPARC. Sounds very strange that they wouldn't support Solaris 11 on X86 as well now that they've gone through the trouble of verifying it on SPARC. Very odd!

Comment: yes is SAP Crystal Server what im trying to install, and im following this particular guide to install it 

https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/tividd/td/TEDW/GC32-0744-03/en_US/HTML/insmst82.htm

Since the documentation in sap isnt very helpfull

currently i have an oracle database 12c running on a VMware machine with solaris 11 trying to add sap crystal server to it, but when i executed the setup.sh that came with the free trial download it gave me the error i specified above

Comment: From your error message it would seem you've downloaded a package for Linux ("LNX" in your path) and now you are trying to install on Solaris. That won't work.

Comment: That could be, after you fill the registration form in sap in order to download the free trial, it shows a download for windows, a download for linux and a download for linux with download manager. 

And if you read the official documentation in sap in: 

http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/crs2016/en/crs2016_install_linux_en.pdf 

it sends you to To:

 download the server installation program
1. Go to https://support.sap.com/home.html > Software Downloads.
3. Select C Crystal Server Crystal Server 2016 .

Asks for an user and password i obviously don`t have